# What is the difference between action-forward and action-mapping

Tags: struts-1

So I have a searchPage.jsp which will search an api and show results on resultPage.jsp. searchForm.java which have getters and setters and have all the variables that will be on the searchPage.jsp form. There is a searchAction page that will call the api. Every page have its own configuration page like search-configuration.xml.

My question

1. How do I get the variables from the searchPage.jsp to searchAction.java using searchForm.java?
2. How do redirect searchPage.jsp take the results from searchAction.jsp and populate the field on the result page?
3. How do I configure the searchPage.jsp to handle this?

- I have gone through this tutorial: https://mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-tutorials/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Via a normal Struts 1 `ActionForm` implementation. The linked tutorial has several examples of action forms and passing data from JSP-to-action`.
2. There are multiple ways to do this; the easiest is by setting a request attribute and accessing it via JSTL<sup>1</sup>. The linked tutorial has several examples of setting request attributes and accessing them in the view layer.
3. Via the normal Struts 1 configuration mechanisms, of which the linked tutorial has several examples.

---

*Remember: Struts 1 was EOLed ~10 years ago, with good reason. Unless there's a specific job still using a dead framework, or you're spelunking Java Web framework history, don't bother.*

---

<sup>1</sup> (JSTL tags should be favored over Struts 1 tags when functionality
overlaps.

Comment: Struts 1 is the only option, but could link the sections? I am now trying to go through a struts survival guide and I'd rather not go through that if I can avoid it. I took it on thinking it was like html and JS but I just didn't know how java frameworks worked.

Comment: @bugsaccount The `<logic:iterate>` section shows setting a request attribute (again, use JSP EL or JSTL instead of S1 tags when functionality overlaps). The `<html:text>` section shows everything but the actual JSP source (but any reasonable S1 tutorial covers form handling).